# Square Register API Error - How to use Sandbox Environment?

Tags: square-connect

I am setting up `Application ID` and `Personal Access` token with Sandbox's values. By Sandbox's `Application ID` I am able to get Sandbox `Location ID` list.

But when my app opens the Register app (now Square Point of Sale), its giving the error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, there is not a sandbox environment for [Square's Point of Sale APIs](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/register-api-overview/). The preferred testing method is to charge and issue refunds. See the following FAQ article: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/faq-register-api-sandbox/

Comment: Good call. Only Connect API v2 (not v1 nor Register API) can use the sandbox as of today. If Square Application ID looks like *sandbox-sq0idp-k0akkOrV9rOd_xl9N0E6eg* then change to real Application ID. If it helps, create a second "Test" Square Application.

Comment: Working with real money to test seems counter-intuitive to test. When will Sandbox be available for register? @tristansokol

Comment: There is not a public release date for this functionality.

Comment: @tristansokol : Is there any update for sandbox testing using SDK and POS app ? as now Square POS requires current location of device so I am not able to even make real transections for testing from India ! :(

Comment: Sorry, no update, but you are not alone and we are working on fixing this experience.

Comment: @tristansokol thanks I will be waiting for new updates